# Cheap webhosts that come with smartfoxserver for flash

Tags: hosting, flash, socket

My current web host doesn't allow socket servers. Can anyone tell me some cheap webhost servers that comes with smartfox server for flash?

Thanks.

Comment: Which do you want, good or cheap?

Comment: Cheap price is the priority - edited.

Comment: Product or Service recommendations are off topic per the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem that there are any webhosts that come with smart fox server installed.

Answer (score 1):

[I'm a shared hosting provider](http://www.internetconnection.net/) that will let you run socket servers and PHP.

Users are prevented from "screwing up everyone else" by using [authbind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authbind) and [iptables](http://www.netfilter.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to find a standard, shared webhost that lets you run an application that uses raw sockets.  It would be too easy to abuse that feature and screw up everyone else on that box.  (Google App Engine, for instance, doesn't even permit raw sockets in their cloud).

You'll have to look at getting a VPS, at a minimum. There are plenty to choose from; a Google search will tell you more than I ever could.  As an example though. I have heard good things about [Slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com/) (though I've never used them myself).  They have a basic $20/mo. VPS plan that should do everything you need.  But you're not going to find something that's like $5/mo. PHP hosting.

Answer (score -1):

No shared host will allow you to use that as mentioned by jamieb.

You're going to either have to get a VPS, I know [BurstNet](http://burst.net) offers then at $10/mo, but that's really the bottom of the barrel and you'll get what you're paying for with them.

If you're willing to spend a little more, I would recommend contacting [ReliableSite.Net](http://www.reliablesite.net/v3/dedicated.asp) to see if they can work out a solution for you.